# Custom mod redirection not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I check out many questions but didn't get my answer so I posted my problem as question I am having issue with rewriting url with htaccess.

My URL :
localhost/index.php?api=param/sub_param&some_key=some_value&some_key2=some_value2

How I want it to rewrite :
localhost/api/param/sub_param?some_key=some_value&some_key2=some_value2

I know the url structure is bit not correct but still I want like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule api/([a-z0-9_]+/[a-z0-9_]+)?([a-z0-9_])=([a-z0-9_])&([a-z0-9_])=([a-z0-9_]) index.php?api=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5
```

I don't know why my code is not working.

It works if I use / instead of question I think the only reason its not working is question mark, but I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You earlier rule wasn't working because you cannot match `QUERY_STRING` using `RewriteRule`. In any case you don't even need to match/capture query string as you just need `QSA` flag here.  `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

You correct rule will be (with more correct regex and flags):

```
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z0-9_]+/[a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?api=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer by my own I don't how its working if anyone can explain it to so I can select his answer

Working code :

```
RewriteRule api/([a-z0-9_]+/[a-z0-9]+) index.php?api=$1 [QSA]
```